# Display PDF in browser using s3 signed url received from service api

Tags: pdf, amazon-s3, angular6

I am trying to display a PDF using a amazon s3 signed url that i got as a response from backend java api service. How can i preview the pdf in a modal instead of downloading it using angular 6?

While using this url as a src in iframe, it downloads the file to browser.

```
previewProtocol(){
  this.service.getPreviewUrl(userId).subscribe((response) => {
    $('#pdfModal').modal("show");
    let url = response;
    this.pdfUrl = this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url);
  },
  (err)=> {
  });
}

<iframe style="height:500px;width:100%;" [src]="pdfUrl"></iframe>
```

Trying to maintain the look of the viewer like that of a browser, hence using iframe.